# Display database table in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to display a table using **CodeIgniter**. I made a function to select all data from one table and display it using a foreach loop when the button is clicked. I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::result() in C:\Xampp\htdocs\Auction\application\models\bidding_model.php on line 47
```

This is my controller page:

```
public function viewauction()
{
    $this->load->model('bidding_model');
    $data['query'] = $this->bidding_model->viewauction();   
    $this->load->view('auction_view', $data);
}
```

This is the model:

```
function viewauction()
{
    $query =  $this->db->select('products'); 
    return $query->result();
}
```

This is the view:

```
<tbody>
<?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
<tr>   
    <td><?php echo $row->product_id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->auction_id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->start_time; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->end_time; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your model method code to

```
function viewauction()
{
    $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('products')->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Hope this helps. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `get()`

`select()` query builder is used for selecting the columns of the table and not the table

example

```
$query = $this->db->select(array('product_id','auction_id'))
                  ->get('products');
return $query->result();
```

if you want to select all you can use the get only,

read more at
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
$query =  $this->db->select('products'); 
return $query->result() ;
```

`$query->result()` is returning false probably because the products table does not exist. you have to use get instead of select.

Try:

```
$query =  $this->db->get('products'); 
return $query->result() ;
```

That could get your started

Answer (score 0):

```
public function select($table, $field, $value)
{
    $this->db->select(*);
    $this->db->from('$table');
    $this->db->where($field, $value);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query;
}
```

I hope the above code will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a simpler way available.

You should get most from the framework features it is providing,

Use, CodeIgniter's Table Library,

```
$this->load->library('table'); // Loading the Table Library 

$query = $this->db->get('table_name'); // the MySQL table name to generate HTML table

echo $this->table->generate($query); // Render of your HTML table
```

You can also modify the behavior of HTML generator if you want some custom things like class in table head or body or anything, which you will almost need.

```
$this->table->set_template($template); // passing an array
```

Use this line after loading the table library. Use keys from the documentation link below.

Reference: [CodeIgniter 3 Table Library - Official Docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/table.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
function viewauction()
{
    $this->db->select('*'); 
    $this->db->from('tablename');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Above code will help you.